# creating short links causes collision

Tags: php, url-shortener

Ok so while trying to create small 3 characters mini record which is then added to mod_rewriten domain url making link/file shortening service i seem to hit a brick wall when it comes to url record collision. Might be the fact that i have not yet deployed any reall validation system to check with MySQL if the record exist and push it to the user or if the record exist for the tag but not the actuall url/file then re-run the script to create a new short tag.

Here is the current script which causes collisions with tag and for some reason creates a file with name different then the tag (this is used for file sharing only)

```
function shorten_file() {

     $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $ltr = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIKLM'; 

 srand((double) microtime() * 1000000); 

 $short = '';
     for ($i = 1; $i <= rand(4,4); $i++) { 
 $q = rand() %98; 
 $short = $short . $ltr[$q];
 }

     $file = strtolower($name);

     $rand = mt_rand();
     $short = substr($rand.$file, 0, 3);

     return $short;

}

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename = str_replace("'", "", $filename);
$ext = $parts[count($parts)-1];
$contenttype = strtolower($ext);

$new_file = shorten($filename).".".$ext;
$new_hash = shorten($filename);
```

As mentioned the records are created so say I upload a file called: img_4032.jpg the file will be uploaded as tmp then it will be processed and a record will be created. Now the file is saved to /server_id (1-8)/files/hash (md5 of a-g)/file_cLO.jpg and a record cLO should be generated but instead i get file_cLO.jpg record lNm, so there we go the script does not return same record as it gives to the file. I will also note that for some reason UPPERCASE letters are not returned so it is all lowercase along with numbers.

Any suggestions on a fix, or possible idea's what to do to prevent this collisions from happening other then validating actuall record which will be added?

All "logical" ideas are welcomed allong with suggestions

Comment: Several issues, why do you repeat the numbers in the $ltr? Also, you basically take the filename, add a random salt, create a SHA1 hash and grab the first 3 characters. Those characters can be 0-9a-z, so that gives 4096 combinations. That means that even after just 3000 links you have more than 50% chance of collision.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö i had the LTR code for years, since late 06, never kind of figured why the numbers where repeated. But now that you pointed out I might as well make it Numbers, Lowercase, Uppercase

Comment: @RogerLindsjö hmm, did change the code. but now its returning numbers only, also do you mind telling me a formula with witch i can calculate collision rate?

Comment: The collision probability is the birthday paradox, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem and I had a brain lapse, the probability of having at least one collation out of 4096 possible values happens passes 50% at 76 numbers.

Comment: Not sure how many URLs you need to shorten, but even if you change the code so you use the full span of 0-1a-zA-Z, then that is still only 238328 unique ids. It takes less than 600 of these randomly chosen to get a 50% collision rate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling the shorten function twice generating a new hash each time, instead call it once and assign that to both vars

```
$new_hash = shorten($filename);
$new_file = $new_hash.".".$ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `shorten` twice, producing two separate random urls (you reseed the random number generator every time you call it).